# DBGrid XE3 background color

Tags: delphi, delphi-xe3, tdbgrid

[image]

```
{*-----------------------------------------------------------------------------
 Unit Name: TopFormU
 @Author Mr. Arch Brooks, Software Engineer, Brooks Computing Systems LLC
 @Version 1.0
 Date:      04-Jan-2014
 Purpose:
 History:
 -----------------------------------------------------------------------------}

unit TopFormU;

interface

uses
  BCSXE3Utilsdp, System.Classes, System.SysUtils, System.Variants,
  TopFormdmU, Vcl.ComCtrls, Vcl.Controls, Vcl.DBCtrls, Vcl.Dialogs,
  Vcl.ExtCtrls, Vcl.Forms, Vcl.Graphics, Vcl.Grids, Vcl.Menus, Vcl.StdCtrls,
  Vcl.TabNotBk, Winapi.Messages, Winapi.Windows, Vcl.DBGrids;

type

  /// Tab Sheet Class
  TTabSheet = class(Vcl.ComCtrls.TTabSheet)
  private
    /// Tab Control Color
    FColor: TColor;
    procedure SetColor(Value: TColor);
    procedure WMEraseBkGnd(var Msg: TWMEraseBkGnd); message WM_ERASEBKGND;
  public
    constructor Create(aOwner: TComponent); override;
    property Color: TColor read FColor write SetColor;
  end;

  /// TopForm Primary Class
  TTopFormC = class(TForm)
    /// BCS XE3 Utilities Component
    BCSXE3UtilsCmp1: TBCSXE3UtilsCmp;
   /// TopForm Color Dialog
    TopFormColor: TColorDialog;
    /// TopForm Colors Menu Item
    TopFormColors1: TMenuItem;
    /// TopForm DB Navigator
    TopFormDBNavigator1: TDBNavigator;
    /// TopForm DB Memo
    TopFormDBMemo1: TDBMemo;
    /// TopForm SB Grid
    TopFormDBGrid1: TDBGrid;
    /// BCSPageColor Main Menu
    TopFormMainMenu1: TMainMenu;
   /// Main Page Control
    TopFormPageControl1: TPageControl;
    /// Help Menu Item
    TopFormHelp1: TMenuItem;
    /// Status Panel For Dialog
    TopFormStatusPanel1: TStatusBar;
    /// Tab sheet 1 for page control
    TopFormTabSheet1: TTabSheet;
    /// Tab sheet 2 for page control
    TopFormTabSheet2: TTabSheet;
    /// Timer for Dialog
    TopFormTimer1: TTimer;

    procedure TopFormColors1Click(Sender: TObject);
    procedure TopFormCreate(Sender: TObject);
    procedure TopFormDrawTab(Control: TCustomTabControl; TabIndex: Integer;
      const Rect: TRect; Active: Boolean);
    procedure TopFormFormActivate(Sender: TObject);
    procedure TopFormGridColor;
    procedure TopFormHelp1Click(Sender: TObject);
    procedure TopFormStatusBar1DrawPanel(StatusBar: TStatusBar;
      Panel: TStatusPanel; const Rect: TRect);
    procedure TopFormTimer1Timer(Sender: TObject);
  public
    {Public declarations}
  end;

var
  /// TopForm Dialog Pointer
  TopFormC: TTopFormC;

implementation

{$R *.dfm}

var
  /// TimeStamp Variable
  ftime: String;
  /// Item Index
  i: Integer;

{*-----------------------------------------------------------------------------
  Procedure: Create
  Date:      04-Jan-2014
  @Param     aOwner: TComponent
  @Return    None

 -----------------------------------------------------------------------------}

constructor TTabSheet.Create(aOwner: TComponent);
begin
  inherited;
  FColor := clWhite;
end;

{*-----------------------------------------------------------------------------
 Procedure: SetColor
 Date:      04-Jan-2014
 @Param     Value: TColor
 @Return    None

 -----------------------------------------------------------------------------}

procedure TTabSheet.SetColor(Value: TColor);
begin
  if FColor &lt;&gt; Value then
  begin
    FColor := Value;
    Invalidate;
  end;
end;

{*-----------------------------------------------------------------------------
 Procedure: WMEraseBkGnd
 Date:      04-Jan-2014
 @Param     var Msg: TWMEraseBkGnd
 @Return    None

 -----------------------------------------------------------------------------}

procedure TTabSheet.WMEraseBkGnd(var Msg: TWMEraseBkGnd);
begin
  if FColor = clBtnFace then
    inherited
  else
  begin
    Brush.Color := FColor;
    FillRect(Msg.dc, ClientRect, Brush.Handle);
    Msg.Result := 1;
  end;
end;

{*-----------------------------------------------------------------------------
 Procedure: TopFormColors1Click
 Date:      04-Jan-2014
 @Param     Sender: TObject
 @Return    None

 -----------------------------------------------------------------------------}

procedure TTopFormC.TopFormColors1Click(Sender: TObject);
var
  ti: Integer;
begin
  if TopFormColor.Execute then
  begin
    Color := TopFormColor.Color;
    TopFormTabSheet1.Color := Color;
    TopFormTabSheet2.Color := Color;
    TopFormDBGrid1.Color := Color;
    TopFormStatusPanel1.Color := Color;
    TopFormGridColor;
    TopFormDBGrid1.Repaint;
  end;
end;

{*-----------------------------------------------------------------------------
 Procedure: TopFormCreate
 Date:      04-Jan-2014
 @Param     Sender: TObject
 @Return    None

 -----------------------------------------------------------------------------}

procedure TTopFormC.TopFormCreate(Sender: TObject);
begin
  Color := $C9FCFA;
  TopFormTabSheet1.Color := Color;
  TopFormTabSheet2.Color := Color;
  TopFormStatusPanel1.Color := Color;
end;

{*-----------------------------------------------------------------------------
 Procedure: TopFormDrawTab
 Date:      04-Jan-2014
 @Param     Control: TCustomTabControl; TabIndex: Integer; const Rect: TRect;
 Active: Boolean
 @Return    None

 -----------------------------------------------------------------------------}

procedure TTopFormC.TopFormDrawTab(Control: TCustomTabControl;
  TabIndex: Integer; const Rect: TRect; Active: Boolean);
var
  AText: string;
  APoint: TPoint;
begin
  with (Control as TPageControl).Canvas do
  begin
    Brush.Color := Color;
    FillRect(Rect);
    AText := TPageControl(Control).Pages[TabIndex].Caption;
    with Control.Canvas do
    begin
      APoint.x := (Rect.Right - Rect.Left) div 2 - TextWidth(AText) div 2;
      APoint.y := (Rect.Bottom - Rect.Top) div 2 - TextHeight(AText) div 2;
      TextRect(Rect, Rect.Left + APoint.x, Rect.Top + APoint.y, AText);
    end;
  end;
end;

{*-----------------------------------------------------------------------------
 Procedure: FormActivate
 Date:      05-Jan-2014
 @Param     Sender: TObject
 @Return    None

 -----------------------------------------------------------------------------}

procedure TTopFormC.TopFormFormActivate(Sender: TObject);
begin
  TopFormDBGrid1.Invalidate;
  TopFormDBGrid1.Color := Color;
  TopFormDBGrid1.Canvas.Brush.Color := Color;
  TopFormDBGrid1.Canvas.Refresh;
  TopFormGridColor;
end;

{*-----------------------------------------------------------------------------
 Procedure: TopFormGridColor
 Date:      05-Jan-2014
 @Param     None
 @Return    None

 -----------------------------------------------------------------------------}

procedure TTopFormC.TopFormGridColor;
begin
  i := 0;
  repeat
    TopFormDBGrid1.Columns[i].Color := Color;
    Inc(i);
  until i &gt; TopFormDBGrid1.Columns.Count - 1;
  TopFormDBGrid1.Repaint;
end;

{*-----------------------------------------------------------------------------
 Procedure: TopFormHelp1Click
 Date:      04-Jan-2014
 @Param     Sender: TObject
 @Return    None

 -----------------------------------------------------------------------------}

procedure TTopFormC.TopFormHelp1Click(Sender: TObject);
begin
  BCSXE3UtilsCmp1.ShellExec('http://bcswebs.us/bcs002/');
end;

{*-----------------------------------------------------------------------------
 Procedure: TopFormStatusBar1DrawPanel
 Date:      04-Jan-2014
 @Param     StatusBar: TStatusBar; Panel: TStatusPanel; const Rect: TRect
 @Return    None

 -----------------------------------------------------------------------------}

procedure TTopFormC.TopFormStatusBar1DrawPanel(StatusBar: TStatusBar;
  Panel: TStatusPanel; const Rect: TRect);
begin
  with StatusBar.Canvas do
  begin
    FillRect(Rect);
    case Panel.Index of
      0: // fist panel
        begin
          Brush.Color := Color;
          Font.Color := clBlack;
          // Font.Style := [fsBold];
          TextRect(Rect, 2 + Rect.Left, 2 + Rect.Top, Panel.Text);
        end;
      1: // second panel
        begin
          Brush.Color := Color;
          Font.Color := clBlack;
          // Font.Style := [fsItalic];
          TextRect(Rect, 2 + Rect.Left, 2 + Rect.Top, Panel.Text);
        end;
      2: // Third panel
        begin
          Brush.Color := Color;
          Font.Color := clBlack;
          // Font.Style := [fsItalic];
          Panel.Text := ftime;
          TextRect(Rect, 2 + Rect.Left, 2 + Rect.Top, Panel.Text);
          TextOut(0, 0, ftime);
        end;
    end;
  end;
end;

{*-----------------------------------------------------------------------------
 Procedure: TopFormTimer1Timer
 Date:      04-Jan-2014
 @Param     Sender: TObject
 @Return    None

 -----------------------------------------------------------------------------}

procedure TTopFormC.TopFormTimer1Timer(Sender: TObject);
begin
  DateTimeToString(ftime, 'dddd, mmmm dd, yyyy hh:mm:ss     ', now);
  TopFormStatusPanel1.Panels[2].Text := ftime;
end;

end.
```

You can see the rows are non white.  The background for the remainder of the grid is white.  How do I fill the white area with a color?

Answer (score 4):

To change the background color of the area not occupied by cells, you must set the `Color` property , but this only works if the `DrawingStyle` property has the *gdsClassic* Value. So in order to keep the themed dbgrid and change the background color you must override the `Paint` method.

try this sample which uses a interposer class

```
type
  TDBGrid = class(Vcl.DBGrids.TDBGrid)
  protected
    procedure Paint; override;
  end;

  TForm1 = class(TForm)
    DbGrid1: TDbGrid;
  ....
  ....

{ TDBGrid }


procedure TDBGrid.Paint;
var
  LDrawInfo: TGridDrawInfo;
begin
  inherited Paint;
  CalcDrawInfo(LDrawInfo);
  if LDrawInfo.Horz.GridBoundary < LDrawInfo.Horz.GridExtent then
  begin
    Canvas.Brush.Color := Color; //use the Color property to paint the background
    Canvas.FillRect(Rect(LDrawInfo.Horz.GridBoundary, 0, LDrawInfo.Horz.GridExtent, LDrawInfo.Vert.GridBoundary));
  end;
  if LDrawInfo.Vert.GridBoundary < LDrawInfo.Vert.GridExtent then
  begin
    Canvas.Brush.Color := Color;//use the Color property to paint the background
    Canvas.FillRect(Rect(0, LDrawInfo.Vert.GridBoundary, LDrawInfo.Horz.GridExtent, LDrawInfo.Vert.GridExtent));
  end;
end;
```